# PDFSharp is overwriting the text

Tags: c#, pdfsharp

I have a problem with PDFSharp, I have a button that when I click to generate the PDF, it is overwriting the text. I have tried many ways to fix it, but I can not. If someone can help me, I would appreciate it.

This is my code:

```
protected void btnPdf_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var idProcessoResposta = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["demanda"]);

        var listaProcesso = new ManterProcesso().ObterDetalhamentoProcesso(idProcessoResposta);

        // Create a new PDF document
        var document = new PdfDocument();

        var qtdEtapa = 0;
        var alturaLinha = 20;
        var margin = 30;
        var tamanhoTituloEtapa = 70;
        var posicaoInicialEtapa = 100;
        var padding = margin + 5;
        var alturaMaximaBlocoCampos = 700;

        foreach (var etapa in listaProcesso.Etapas)
        {
            // Create an empty page
            var page = document.AddPage();
            page.Size = PdfSharp.PageSize.A4;
            page.Orientation = PdfSharp.PageOrientation.Portrait;

            // Get an XGraphics object for drawing
            var gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);

            // Create a font
            var font = new XFont("Verdana", 10);
            var textFormatter = new XTextFormatter(gfx);

            var gruposCampos = new List<DtoBlocoCampo>();

            var grupoIndex = 0;
            var alturaBloco = 0;

            foreach (var campo in etapa.ListaCampos)
            {
                var alturaCampo =
                    CalcularAlturaCampo(gfx.MeasureString(campo.Titulo + ": " + campo.Resposta, font).Width,
                        (int) page.Width, alturaLinha);

                alturaBloco += alturaCampo;

                // Atualizar a altura do bloco.
                if (gruposCampos.Any() && gruposCampos[grupoIndex] != null)
                {
                    var altura = gruposCampos[grupoIndex].AlturaBloco;
                    var novaAltura = alturaBloco + (gruposCampos[grupoIndex].PossuiEspacoAntes ? tamanhoTituloEtapa : 0);

                    gruposCampos[grupoIndex].AlturaBloco = altura > novaAltura ? altura : novaAltura;
                }

                // Verificar se o bloco possui espaço antes, para as informações da Etapa.
                var possuiEspacoAntes = true;

                // Se os campos atingirem o limite da exibição, pular para a próxima página.
                // Dá um espaço em cima de 3 linhas para o conteúdo da etapa.
                if (alturaBloco > (alturaMaximaBlocoCampos - (alturaLinha * 3)))
                {
                    alturaBloco = 0;
                    grupoIndex++;
                    possuiEspacoAntes = false;
                }

                if (gruposCampos.Count() != grupoIndex + 1)
                {
                    gruposCampos.Add(new DtoBlocoCampo(possuiEspacoAntes, tamanhoTituloEtapa + alturaBloco ));
                }

                gruposCampos[grupoIndex].Campos.Add(campo);
            }

            foreach (var grupoCampos in gruposCampos)
            {
                gfx.DrawRectangle(XPens.Black, XBrushes.White,
                    new XRect(alturaLinha, grupoCampos.PossuiEspacoAntes ? posicaoInicialEtapa : 20, page.Width - 45,
                        grupoCampos.AlturaBloco));

                if (gruposCampos.IndexOf(grupoCampos) == 0)
                {
                    EscreverHeaderEtapa(textFormatter, idProcessoResposta, listaProcesso, page, font, qtdEtapa,
                        etapa, padding, grupoCampos.PossuiEspacoAntes ? posicaoInicialEtapa : 20, alturaLinha, gfx);
                }

                //Campos
                var qtdCampos = 0;

                foreach (var campo in grupoCampos.Campos)
                {
                    // Escrever dados do Campo.
                    EscreverCampo(campo, gfx, font, page, alturaLinha, textFormatter, padding, posicaoInicialEtapa,
                        qtdCampos, tamanhoTituloEtapa, grupoCampos.PossuiEspacoAntes);

                    qtdCampos++;
                }

                // Se não for a última página, adiciona mais uma página ao PDF.
                if (gruposCampos.IndexOf(grupoCampos) != gruposCampos.Count() - 1)
                {
                    page = document.AddPage();
                    gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);
                    textFormatter = new XTextFormatter(gfx);
                }
            }

            // Dar continuidade ao número da etapa.
            qtdEtapa++;
        }

        var streamOutput = new MemoryStream();
        document.Save(streamOutput, false);

        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition",
            "attachment; filename=historicoDemanda_" + idProcessoResposta + ".pdf");
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.BinaryWrite(streamOutput.ToArray());
        Response.Flush();
    }

    private static void EscreverHeaderEtapa(XTextFormatter textFormatter, int idProcessoResposta,
        DTODetalhamentoProcesso listaProcesso, PdfPage page, XFont font, int qtdEtapa, DTOEtapaInfo etapa,
        int padding,
        int posicaoInicialEtapa, int alturaLinha, XGraphics gfx)
    {
        textFormatter.Alignment = XParagraphAlignment.Left;

        // Demanda
        textFormatter.DrawString("#" + idProcessoResposta + " - " + listaProcesso.Processo.Nome,
            new XFont("Verdana", 10, XFontStyle.Bold), XBrushes.Black,
            new XRect(30, 20, page.Width - 60, page.Height - 30));

        // Demandante
        textFormatter.DrawString("Demandado por: " + listaProcesso.Processo.Demandante, font, XBrushes.Black,
            new XRect(30, 50, page.Width - 60, page.Height - 30));

        // Data de Solicitacao
        textFormatter.DrawString("Data de Solicitação: " + listaProcesso.Processo.DataSolicitacao, font,
            XBrushes.Black, new XRect(30, 70, page.Width - 60, page.Height - 30));

        // Nome da Etapa
        textFormatter.DrawString((qtdEtapa + 1) + " - ETAPA: " + etapa.Nome,
            new XFont("Verdana", 10, XFontStyle.Bold), XBrushes.Black,
            new XRect(padding, (posicaoInicialEtapa + 5), page.Width - 60, page.Height - 30));

        // Requer Aprovação 
        textFormatter.DrawString("Requer Aprovação: " + ((etapa.RequerAprovacao) ? "SIM" : "NÃO"), font,
            XBrushes.Black,
            new XRect(padding, (posicaoInicialEtapa + alturaLinha), (page.Width/2), page.Height - 30));

        // Situacao
        textFormatter.DrawString("Status: " + etapa.Situacao.Nome, font, XBrushes.Black,
            new XRect((page.Width/2), (posicaoInicialEtapa + alturaLinha), (page.Width/2), page.Height - 30));

        // Concluido por
        textFormatter.DrawString(ObterNomeDoAnalista(etapa, gfx, font, page.Width, padding), font, XBrushes.Black,
            new XRect(padding, (posicaoInicialEtapa + alturaLinha + alturaLinha), (page.Width/2), page.Height - 30));

        // Data de Preenchimento
        textFormatter.DrawString("Data de Preenchimento: " + etapa.DataPreenchimento, font, XBrushes.Black,
            new XRect((page.Width/2), (posicaoInicialEtapa + alturaLinha + alturaLinha), (page.Width/2),
                page.Height - 30));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Obter o nome do analista. Caso o nome seja muito grande, começa a abreviar os nomes depois do primeiro nome.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="etapa"></param>
    /// <param name="gfx"></param>
    /// <param name="font"></param>
    /// <param name="pageWidth"></param>
    /// <param name="padding"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static string ObterNomeDoAnalista(DTOEtapaInfo etapa, XGraphics gfx, XFont font, double pageWidth, int padding)
    {
        var texto = etapa.Situacao.Nome + " por " + etapa.Analista.Nome.ToUpper();

        var metadeWidth = pageWidth/2;

        var nome = etapa.Analista.Nome;

        while (gfx.MeasureString(texto, font).Width > metadeWidth - padding)
        {
            var nomes = nome.Split(' ');

            var atingiuLimite = false;

            // 'i = 1' para pular o primeiro nome.
            for (var i = 1; i < nomes.Length; i++)
            {
                if (ObterPronomes(true).Contains(nomes[i]) == false && nomes[i].Length != 2)
                {
                    nomes[i] = nomes[i].Substring(0, 1) + ".";
                    break;
                }

                // Se chegou no final, não há mais nada pra abreviar, então só retorna o que deu.
                if (i == nomes.Length - 1)
                {
                    atingiuLimite = true;
                }
            }

            texto = etapa.Situacao.Nome.Trim() + " por " + (nome = string.Join(" ", nomes)).ToUpper();

            if (atingiuLimite)
                return texto;
        }

        return texto;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Retornar uma lista de pronomes.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="maiusculas">True: Retorna a lista com todos os pronomes em letras maiúsculas.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static List<string> ObterPronomes(bool maiusculas = false)
    {
        var lista = new List<string>
        {
            "de",
            "do",
            "da",
            "das",
            "dos"
        };

        return maiusculas
            ? lista.Select(x => x.ToUpper()).ToList()
            : lista;
    }

    private void EscreverCampo(DTOCampo campo, XGraphics gfx, XFont font, PdfPage page, int alturaLinha,
        XTextFormatter textFormatter, int padding, int posicaoInicialEtapa, int qtdCampos, int tamanhoTituloEtapa, bool possuiEspacoAntes)
    {
        textFormatter.Alignment = XParagraphAlignment.Left;

        var alturaCampo = CalcularAlturaCampo(gfx.MeasureString(campo.ObterTexto(), font).Width, (int) page.Width,
            alturaLinha);

        var rect = new XRect(padding,
            ((possuiEspacoAntes ? posicaoInicialEtapa : 40) +
             (alturaLinha*qtdCampos) +
             (possuiEspacoAntes ? tamanhoTituloEtapa : 0)), page.Width - 60, alturaCampo);

        textFormatter.DrawString(campo.ObterTexto(), font, XBrushes.Black, rect);
    }

    private int CalcularAlturaCampo(double larguraBruta, int larguraMaximaPagina, int alturaLinha)
    {
        var resultado = alturaLinha;
        if (larguraBruta > larguraMaximaPagina)
        {
            var qtdLinhas = (larguraBruta / larguraMaximaPagina);
            resultado = (((int)qtdLinhas + 1) * alturaLinha);
        }

        return resultado;
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe helpful: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266563/do-non-english-words-increase-the-probability-of-receiving-downvotes/

Answer (score 0):

You are recreating a new pdf everytime. Sounds like what you want to do is "Add" a new page. In which case see below:

`

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Imports all pages from a list of documents.
    /// </summary>
static void Variant1()
{
  // Get some file names
  string[] files = GetFiles();
&nbsp;
  // Open the output document
  PdfDocument outputDocument = new PdfDocument();
    &nbsp;
      // Iterate files
      foreach (string file in files)
      {
        // Open the document to import pages from it.
        PdfDocument inputDocument = PdfReader.Open(file,             PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import);
    &nbsp;
        // Iterate pages
        int count = inputDocument.PageCount;
        for (int idx = 0; idx < count; idx++)
        {
          // Get the page from the external document...
          PdfPage page = inputDocument.Pages[idx];
          // ...and add it to the output document.
          outputDocument.AddPage(page);
        }
      }
    &nbsp;
      // Save the document...
      const string filename = "ConcatenatedDocument1_tempfile.pdf";
      outputDocument.Save(filename);
      // ...and start a viewer.
      Process.Start(filename);
    }
`
```